# Send tile notification - windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Helo,
I want to ask you, if I can send tile notification from one phone to another phone and vice versa using WCF service?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send push to other phone you have to have ChannelURI. There is good article about it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx

When you have this adress you have to send special XML data

```
        string textTitle = tbxTitle.Text;
        string textSubtitle = tbxSubtitle.Text;

        string deviceUri = tbxUri.Text;

        string msg =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                "<wp:Toast>" +
                "<wp:Text1>" + textTitle + "</wp:Text1>" +
                "<wp:Text2>" + textSubtitle + "</wp:Text2>" +
                "</wp:Toast>" +
            "</wp:Notification>";

        byte[] msgBytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(msg);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(channelUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = msg.Length;
        request.Headers["X-MessageID"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        request.Headers["X-WindowsPhone-Target"] = "toast";
        request.Headers["X-NotificationClass"] = "2";

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: So I need to know both uri addresses?

Comment: No, you have to know only reciever address. Each phone have to have address second phone